# How to create a settings page to manage installed language packs?

Tags: android

I've got Tesseract OCR to work with my android app. Basically it extracts text from photos but it requires trained data files for a particular language to be downloaded and extracted first (all available at https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list)

The question is how to create a settings page that manages all the languages, so user can just tap on any language that he wants and it will download and extract it automatically?

Something like...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL7HY.png

and when user taps on a language, it will download and extract automatically

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? It is an Activity with a ListView with items in it... Which of that part is not working?

Comment: I've seen many apps with almost the same style of the page for managing packages and just wondering if there's a base class from Google that we could use, or someone who've already done similar thing and posted production ready code on GitHub that handles the stuff.
For me it's always better to import someone else's library that have been tested over time than reinventing a wheel that I'm not even sure it will be a good wheel..